# How to model normal distributed sensor measurements by day time?

Tags: probability, distribution, gaussian, probability-density

I have a sensor that gives me some value every x minutes. In my database I store the values grouped by hour. So the input domain is an integer between 0 and 23. I want to learn the parameters for a Gaussian distribution (mean and variance). At the end I want to get the probability of a certain measurement level at any given time (hour of day).

The problem is that the peak of the distribution could be at midnight and in the afternoon there could be the minimum. In this case I have no idea how to model it with a Gaussian as the normal distribution does not seem to be suited for "circular" domains (after 23h comes 0h and not 24h, so it is not really continuous).

How could this be modeled? Can I use a normal Gaussian here or should I go for another kind of probability model?

Example:

[image: Sample distribution]

Here I would expect the model to have mean = 23 or 0. But I guess when I learn parameters here, the mean would be exactly in the middle, because a Gaussian only has one peak.

Comment: It's not clear what's going on here. My advice is to say specifically what are the data (what process is this, how are the data collected) and give a short list of example values. What is the figure showing exactly -- what is the vertical axis? Sorry I can't be more helpful at present.

Comment: Several things make me suspect you're off-track here.  1) Means of integer-valued processes are not necessarily integer.  For instance the mean of 6-sided die rolls for a fair die is 3.5; 2) Gaussians have an infinite  range, and I suspect negative values would make you unhappy; and 3) what you're describing sounds like time series data, and sequential observations may be correlated.